# tcpdf edit footer

Tags: edit, footer, tcpdf

How do I edit a footer using tcpdf?  I want to add current date & time at the footer. Please help.

Answer (score 22):

Override the class like this :

```
class MYPDF extends TCPDF {
    public function Footer() {
        $image_file = "img/bg_bottom_releve.jpg";
        $this->Image($image_file, 11, 241, 189, '', 'JPG', '', 'T', false, 300, '', false, false, 0, false, false, false);

        $this->SetY(-15);
        $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'N', 6);
        $this->Cell(0, 5, date("m/d/Y H\hi:s"), 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
    }
}
```

then instead of calling :

```
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
```

do :

```
$pdf = new MYPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
```

Comment: By using this code date shown in the middle but I want to show the date in the left corner what should I do?

Answer (score 6):

You have to extend the TCPDF class and override the Footer() method as explained on the default example n. 3. Check the official http://www.tcpdf.org website and forums for further information.

Answer (score 3):

How can I create 2 footer lines, please?

```
class MYPDF extends TCPDF {
    private $customFooterText = "";

    /**
     * @param string $customFooterText
     */
    public function setCustomFooterText($customFooterText)
    {
        $this->customFooterText = $customFooterText;
    }

    public function Footer()
    {
        $this->SetY(-15);
        // Set font
        $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'I', 8);
        // Page number
        $this->Cell(0, 10, $this->customFooterText, 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
    }
}
```

Usage

```
$pdf = new MYPDF();
$pdf->setCustomFooterText('THIS IS CUSTOM FOOTER');
```

Comment: For multiple lines of text I think it's easier to use HTML, defining it in $mycustomfootertxt:  Replace $this->Cell line with $this->writeHTML($mycustomfootertxt, false, true, false, true);

Answer (score 1):

If you want dynamically change footer text extends TCPDF like this

```
class MYPDF extends TCPDF {

    private $customFooterText = "";

    /**
     * @param string $customFooterText
     */
    public function setCustomFooterText($customFooterText)
    {
        $this->customFooterText = $customFooterText;
    }

    public function Footer()
    {
        $this->SetY(-15);
        // Set font
        $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'I', 8);
        // Page number
        $this->Cell(0, 10, $this->customFooterText, 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
    }

}
```

usage:

```
$pdf = new MYPDF();
$pdf->setCustomFooterText('THIS IS CUSTOM FOOTER');
// .... etc
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want put an different content on more than one page:

```
define("bottom_info", "|FIRST PAGE|SECOND PAGE|THIRD PAGE|...", true);
```

the info will be separated by " | " (with explode function)

class:

```
class MYPDF extends TCPDF {

public function Header() {
}

// Page footer
public function Footer() {
    $this->SetY(-15);       
    $this->SetFont('helvetica', '', 7);
    // Page number      
    $titulos = explode("|",bottom_info);        
    $this->Cell(0, 10,  $titulos[$this->page].' - Pagina '.$this->getAliasNumPage().'/'.$this->getAliasNbPages(), 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

After the **EOD** use the below code to overwrite the footer method.

```
 EOD;

 $txt = date("m/d/Y h:m:s");    

 // print a block of text using Write()
 $pdf->Write($h=0, $txt, $link='', $fill=0, $align='C', $ln=true, $stretch=0, $firstline=false, $firstblock=false, $maxh=0);
```

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out and here's the solution for others that might come across this thread.

Edit the file "tcpdf.php".

Search for "`public function Footer()`"

Add timestamp here:

```
$timestamp = date("m/d/Y h:m:s");

if (empty($this->pagegroups)) {

$pagenumtxt = ' Created on ' .$timestamp.'   '.$this->l['w_page'].' '.$this->getAliasNumPage().' / '.$this->getAliasNbPages();

} else {

$pagenumtxt = ' Created on ' .$timestamp.'   '. $this->l['w_page'].' '.$this->getPageNumGroupAlias().' / '.$this->getPageGroupAlias();

}
```

Comment: This got voted down because it's better to extend the class and override the method than to edit the source as suggested in this answer. HTH

Comment: Btw: in many cases you can't edit dependencies like TCPDF because otherwise you have to add it to your repository