# removing bottom line in tcpdf except page number

Tags: php, tcpdf

I'm using `TCPDF` to generating `PDF` file. I want to remove the bottom line and for that I'm using `$pdf->SetPrintFooter(false);` it is working but after bottom line it is showing page number like this `1/1`, now I only want to remove the bottom line except the page number. Is there any alternative for this in `TCPDF`.

Comment: You can try it by extending, as explained here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824423/tcpdf-edit-footer.

Comment: I check that already but didn't work for me.

Comment: Is anyone who can help me for this please.

Comment: You want do something like that -> http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_003.pdf ?

Answer (score 3):

After creating the object, you need to invoke these commands:

```
$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand, you want that or something like that -> http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_003.pdf

The code is here -> http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_003.phps

I isolated the code you need

```
// Page footer
public function Footer() {
    // Position at 15 mm from bottom
    $this->SetY(-15);
    // Set font
    $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'I', 8);
    // Page number
    $this->Cell(0, 10, 'Page '.$this->getAliasNumPage().'/'.$this->getAliasNbPages(), 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
}
```

If you search something about TCPDF search [here](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php) before asking